# THREE.js update TorusGeometry with GSAP

Tags: three.js, geometry, gsap

I've added a TorusGeometry in my scene and I'm trying to animate it's angle with a smooth transition (I have GSAP in mind). Also, I don't know if a TorusGeometry is the right way to achieve what I'm looking for, I'm relatively new with THREE.js. Here's my Torus code :

```
geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(20, 3, 10, 20, 0);
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
mesh     = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

I've set the angle at 0 and I'd like to increase it by 10deg each time I click the "spacebar" key for instance. I've tried to update the parameters in the scene.render loop like this just to test if it's working or not (it's not) :

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true
mesh.geometry.parameters.angle = Math.PI / 2
```

Here's a codepen preview : https://codepen.io/JeromeRenders/full/abzmPrd

Any advice ? I've been struggling on this for the past few days trying to find a solution but can't seem to find it on my own

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Jérôme. It's best to include a minimal demo along with your answer. You're a lot more likely to get a response if you do so. Sites like jsfiddle or CodePen are great for them.

Comment: Yup I've added a quick codepen demo in my post above ;) thanks :)

Comment: From what I can see, [TorusGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry) has an arc parameter, but I can't see an angle parameter.

Comment: Yes, but when I set the arc parameter, I cant update it when I press a key or any other event in the render/update/loop scene function :-/

Comment: You can't update arc like this, you need a new TorusGeometry